# Angular UI Grid additional selection column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

in Angular UI Grid there is a selection plugin which can be easily enabled and configured.(enableRowSelection,enableSelectAll,...)
What would be the easiest way to have a second selection column (to check/select another criteria per row)? Do I need to add an additional column and implement all the logic on my own, or is there a simple way to extend the existing selection plugin?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i was trying to delete that column, but i see some people think just 1 is even not enough

Answer (score 0):

it's been solved quite easily: just add an additional column using a cell template that saves the state to a row entity property. Additional states/functionality can be handled using ng-change and handling over the current row to a function.

```
cellTemplate: '<div><input type="checkbox" class="overWrite" data-ng-model="row.entity.overWrite" data-ng-change="grid.appScope.changeOverWriteSelection(row)"/></div>'
```